# 3D graph in Octave is not corresponding with entered function

Tags: matlab, function, graph, plot, octave

I'm new to MATLAB/Octave and I'm trying to print a function in a mesh grid.

```
 tx = linspace(-10,10);
 ty = linspace(-10,10);
 [X, Y] = meshgrid (tx, ty);
 Z = (2*X*X*sqrt(2)*Y)/3;
 figure
 mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

What I expect this to do is display a graph in the range Y = from -10 to 10 and X = from -10 to 10.
That's what I get, except the Z values are somewhere in the range -6*10^(-11) across the entire graph, when for the point (10, 10) it should be 942 for example. So the graph is completely off. Did I enter the function wrong or what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using matrix multiplication, use elementwise multiplication instead:

```
Z = (2.*X.*X.*sqrt(2).*Y)./3;
```

This is propably what you are looking for.